# python opencv2, error camera interface, only cam light

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, opencv3.0, opencv, python

This is the code for *opencv2 Takeimage* button.
It doesn't work properly, only the cam light on, but camera interface doesn't show:

```py
def TakeImage():
    Id=(txt.get())
    name=(txt2.get())
    if(is_number(Id) and name.isalpha()):
        Video= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalfacedafults_.xml"
        detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath)
        sampleNum=0
        while(True):
            ret,img=Video.read();
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces=detector.DetectMultiScale(gray,1.2,5);
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.recatangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                sampleNum=sampleNum+1
                cv2.imwrite("TrainImages\ "+name +"."+Id +'.'+str(samlpeNum)+".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+h])
                cv2.imshow('Frame',img)
            if cv2.waitKey(100) &0XFF == ord('s'):
                break
            elif sample>60:
                break
        Video.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        res = "Images Saved for ID: "+ Id + " Name : "+ name
        row = [Id, Name]
        with open ('studentDetails\studentDetails.csv','a+') as csvFile:
             writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
             writer.writerow(row)
             csvFile.close()
             message.configure(text=res)
    else:
        if(is_number(Id)):
            res ="Enter Alphabetical Name"
            message.configure(text= res)
        if (name.isalpha()):
            res="Enter Numberic Id"
            message.configure(text=res)
```

Error showing:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\face reconiger system.py", line 87, in TakeImage
>       faces=detector.DetectMultiScale(gray,1.2,5); AttributeError: 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute 'DetectMultiScale'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the .xml file looks incorrect. You need to replace the following line:

```
harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalfacedafults_.xml"
```

with

```
harcascadePath = cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
```